# Use tidy evaluation when passing an expression as a character to ggplot2::aes()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to convert my use of ggplot2 in functions to using tidy evaluation so as to avoid the warning messages that are evaluated. I particular, I have extensively used aes_string() and these need to be converted to aes(). I can handle cases when just the name of a column is passed as a characater. However, I have been unable to work how to deal with the case when the character is a mathematical expression.

Here is a small reproducible example of the problem that I an trying to solve.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))
xvar <- 'x+100'
yvar <- 'y'

#This works but uses the deprecated aes_string
ggplot(dat,aes_string(x=xvar,y=yvar))

#This works
ggplot(dat, ggplot2::aes(x=x+100, y=.data[[yvar]]))  + geom_point()

#This does not work
ggplot(dat, aes(x={{xvar}}, y=.data[[yvar]])) + geom_point()
```

My question is what tidy evaluation techniques do I need to employ to use xvar to specify the x variable as is possible with aes_string()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `eval(str2expression())`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = eval(str2expression(xvar)), y = eval(str2expression(yvar)))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = xvar, y = yvar)
```

Or using the analogous rlang functions:

```
library(rlang)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = eval_tidy(parse_expr(xvar)), y = eval_tidy(parse_expr(yvar)))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = xvar, y = yvar)
```

[image]

Note you’ll want to manually set the axis labels using `labs()`; otherwise you’ll end up with e.g. `"eval(str2expression(xvar))"` for the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

It may need `parse_expr/eval`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=eval(rlang::parse_expr(xvar)), y=.data[[yvar]])) + 
     geom_point() +
     xlab(xvar)
```

-output

[image]

---

Or another option would be to interpolate and do the `eval/parse`

```
eval(parse(text = glue::glue("ggplot(dat, aes(x = {xvar}, y = {yvar}))",
    "+ geom_point()")))
```